# /etc/init.d/nginx not executable

Tags: nginx, debian, phusion-passenger

I searched on the internet for a while now and I don't find a solution so I am asking here: My question is, why is this file (`/etc/init.d/nginx`) not executeable?

I was following the tutorial of [Alex](https://alexpearce.me/2012/06/setting-up-a-vps/) yesterday and I got into an issue. Everything worked until the `service nginx restart`-command. When I try to run this command I will get

```
 nginx: You don't have permissions to execute nginx.
```

After googling some time I found a potential answer, but this was already done in the tutorial/walkthrough of Alex:

```
 $ sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/nginx
```

**Some info if you don't want to read the tutorial:**

- I am using Nginx (as you will know when reading this bit)
- It's installed it with Passenger and then imported a Nginx Init-script and the nginx.conf file from scratch.
- Oh and I am running Debian instead of Ubuntu, but that shouldn;t be the problem, or?

So I would be very thankful if anyone could help me. Thanks!

Comment: had `/etc/init.d/nginx` been executabe, then you'd been able to run the service script without permission denied. Check `ls -l /etc/init.d/nginx` and you'll see that it's not.

Comment: What do you mean? It's an executable, but sadly it's also permission denied with sudo.

Comment: I am no nginx guy. Few questions, as which user you are running the webserver when you are restarting and can you strace the failed step please. And by that, I mean this, strace -ffttTo /tmp/strace.out <command>

Comment: I am using the root user. So normally sudo isn't needed.

Answer (score 1):

First /etc/init.d/nginx is actually a init script, not an executable file. You could try to locate the nginx binary and start it manually and check the permissions.

Run whereis nginx to find the binary.

Comment: Init scripts are *supposed* to run...

Comment: I used ’which nginx’ but it didn't help. It doesnt output anything.

Comment: Are you using the /opt prefix (default for you) or /etc? Because if you chose somewhere non-standard you may need to manually edit /etc/init.d/nginx so that the path to nginx binary is correct.

Answer (score 0):

How did you install nginx? Have you made sure that you didn't skip a step somewhere?

If you installed it by hand from sources, why? Isn't a package available for your Linux distribution/other Unix? Going the "install from sources" route isn't a good idea (your system doesn't know about it and its dependencies; also *you* are shouldering the burden of keeping up with bugs/security issues, which are specially critical for Internet-facing services).

Comment: As written before, I installed Nginx through Phusion Passenger

Comment: @DominikSchmidt, why don't you use the Debian package? They know what they are doing, and the correct installation is critical for a Internet-facing sevice...

Comment: Sure, but I am working in a serious web development studio and they are also doing it this way. Passenger is installing a Nginx installation from scratch.